How to use freezeReactiveValue to ensure picker options are in sync with data
Good morning all!
I've been trying to get this sorted for a few days now and unable to resolve it.
I have a large table with many options which the user is filtering. As this table is fairly large (million or so rows) and has many interacting options, I want the users options to keep up with their choices i.e. if they use picker 1 to select option a, then picker 2 will only show them the options in line with their first filter e.g.



col1
col2




A
1


A
2


A
3


B
4



if picker for col1 is A
then picker for col2 should show 1,2,3 and not 4
This can then extend to many different columns.
I've followed a few tutorials mainly https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html and https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/45813fd5b4ae6b418cc8a081e8d21830 however these both demand that the user starts at a beginning. I want the user to be able to start with any picker.
I have tried to incorporate freezeReactiveValue in but cant seem to get it to work.
My example for this is as follows
library(shiny)

df <- mtcars %>% 
    rownames_to_column(var = "car")

car_choices <- c("All", unique(df$car))
cyl_choices <- c("All",unique(df$cyl))

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(
                inputId = "car_btn",
                label = "car",
                choices = car_choices,
                selected = "All"
            ),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "cyl_btn",
                label = "cyl",
                choices = cyl_choices,
                selected = "All"
            )
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    data <- reactive({
        df %>% 
            filter(car %in% car_sel(),
                   cyl %in% cyl_sel())
    })
    
    car_sel <- reactive({
        req(input$car_btn)
        if(input$car_btn == "All"){car_choices[-1]}else{input$car_btn}
    })
    
    observeEvent(data(), ignoreInit = T, {
        choices <- c("All", unique(data()$car))
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "car_btn", choices = choices, selected = input$car_btn)
    })
    
    cyl_sel <- reactive({
        req(input$cyl_btn)
        if(input$cyl_btn == "All"){cyl_choices[-1]}else{input$cyl_btn}
    })
    
    observeEvent(data(), ignoreInit = T, {
        choices <- c("All", unique(data()$cyl))
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "cyl_btn", choices = choices, selected = input$cyl_btn)
        
    })
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

        Sys.sleep(1)#added to slow the reactives down to mimic a large table being filtered
        
        data() %>%
            ggplot(aes(x=cyl))+
            geom_bar()
        
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

this works but can create options which are no longer applicable as the data flows through the reactives. If I add freezeReactiveValue which should stop all dependencies until everything has been worked through the app never resolves.
library(shiny)

df <- mtcars %>% 
    rownames_to_column(var = "car")

car_choices <- c("All", unique(df$car))
cyl_choices <- c("All",unique(df$cyl))

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(
                inputId = "car_btn",
                label = "car",
                choices = car_choices,
                selected = "All"
            ),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "cyl_btn",
                label = "cyl",
                choices = cyl_choices,
                selected = "All"
            )
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    data <- reactive({
        df %>% 
            filter(car %in% car_sel(),
                   cyl %in% cyl_sel())
    })
    
    car_sel <- reactive({
        req(input$car_btn)
        if(input$car_btn == "All"){car_choices[-1]}else{input$car_btn}
    })
    
    observeEvent(data(), ignoreInit = T, {
        freezeReactiveValue(input, "car_btn") #freeze added
        choices <- c("All", unique(data()$car))
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "car_btn", choices = choices, selected = input$car_btn)
    })
    
    cyl_sel <- reactive({
        req(input$cyl_btn)
        if(input$cyl_btn == "All"){cyl_choices[-1]}else{input$cyl_btn}
    })
    
    observeEvent(data(), ignoreInit = T, {
        freezeReactiveValue(input, "cyl_btn") #freeze added
        choices <- c("All", unique(data()$cyl))
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "cyl_btn", choices = choices, selected = input$cyl_btn)
        
    })
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

        Sys.sleep(1)
        
        data() %>%
            ggplot(aes(x=cyl))+
            geom_bar()
        
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something here!!
Any help would be much appreciated.

Please check shinyWidgets::selectizeGroupUI.

just the ticket!

The way I approach this situation is to compute each filter separately and
then find the available choices based on what other filters leave available.
library(shiny)

tbl <- data.frame(x = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), y = c(1, 2, 2, 3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("x", "x", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  selectInput("y", "y", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  tableOutput("tbl"),  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x_matches <- reactive(!isTruthy(input$x) | tbl$x %in% input$x)
  y_matches <- reactive(!isTruthy(input$y) | tbl$y %in% input$y)
  
  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    tbl[x_matches() & y_matches(), , drop = FALSE]
  })
  
  x_choices <- reactive(unique(tbl$x[y_matches()]))
  y_choices <- reactive(unique(tbl$y[x_matches()]))
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "x", choices = x_choices(), selected = isolate(input$x))
  })
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "y", choices = y_choices(), selected = isolate(input$y))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

